# OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server returned message "ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name"

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have setup a linked server from SQL Server to a Oracle database. Connection has been tested as successfully. I use the following to query a table from SQL Server and it successfully returned me the result set:

```
EXEC ('select * from tablename') AT [linkedservername]
```

I ran the following from the Oracle database, it(stored procedure) works:

```
EXEC schemaname.storedprocedurename
```

However, when I ran this from SQL server, it returned me the error message `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

```
EXEC('call schemaname.storedprocedurename') AT [linkedservername]
```

Anyone has any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: `EXEC [RemoteServer].DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName`

Answer (score 0):

Matt,
You are missing the () after the procedure name.

```
EXEC('call schemaname.storedprocedurename()') AT [linkedservername]
```

Also, make sure of the following

1. The account being used to link the servers has access to the stored procedure (schema)
2. Sometimes you may need to omit the schema name and just do the 'Call SPName()'